# How to read multi-dimensional values from xml file?

Tags: linq-to-xml

I tried but could not get it? Here is the xml file

```
<Root>
    <Data>
        <Keys>Key1, key2, key3, key4</Keys>
        <FirstRow>Key1row1, Key2Row1, Key3Row1, Key4Row1</FirstRow>
        <SecondRow>Key1Row2, Key2Row2, Key3Row2, Key4Row2</SecondRow>
        <ThirdRow>Key1Row3, Key2Row3, Key2Row3, Key2Row3</ThirdRow>
        and so on .........
    </Data>
</Root>
```

I need to use Linq to XML:-

```
    var data = from d in xDoc.Root.Element("Data")
                              select d;
    foreach(var d in data)
    {
        ...
    }
```

I like to have a M-d array mapping of **comma separated** keys value with is **comma separated** Rows values.

```
Key1      key2        key3       key4
Key1row1  key2Row1    Key3Row1   Key4Row1
....
```

Comment: Is that the actual XML schema? Somebody actually decided to give each row element a different name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The row elements can be iterated (as done), but it'll take `string.Split` (or a more advanced parser) to decompose the row values themselves. In the following example it is done in the `RowTextToValues` method.

Here is a [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net) example (run as "C# Program") with some hints:

```cs
IEnumerable<string> RowTextToValues (string v) {
    return v.Split(new [] {", "}, StringSplitOptions.None);
}

XDocument TestDoc() {
    return XDocument.Parse(@"
    <Root>
        <Data>
            <Keys>Key1, key2, key3, key4</Keys>
            <FirstRow>Key1row1, Key2Row1, Key3Row1, Key4Row1</FirstRow>
            <SecondRow>Key1Row2, Key2Row2, Key3Row2, Key4Row2</SecondRow>
            <ThirdRow>Key1Row3, Key2Row3, Key2Row3, Key2Row3</ThirdRow>
        </Data>
    </Root>");
}

void Main()
{
    var dataNode = TestDoc().Root.Element("Data");

    // -> IEnumerable<XElement>
    var rows = dataNode.Elements();

    // -> IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>>
    var res = rows
        .Select(r => RowTextToValues(r.Value));

    res.Dump();
}
```

Converting to an 2-dimensional array or handling more complex rules is left as an exercise.